# python How to convert the input value into a mathematical function

Tags: python

How to convert an input value into a function!

```
x = int(input('Enter x value: '))
n = str(input('Enter n value: ')) #n= 2 * x ^ 2 - 2 * x + 2
def f(x,n):
    return 2 * x ^ 2 - 2 * x + 2
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking? Your code seems to be taking input and defining functions just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think,you are asking .
How to convert an input value into a mathmetical expression ?

If it is so !

use eval()
in python

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `eval`.

```
x=int(input('...'))
n=input('...') # note that input returns a string

def f(x):
   global n
   return(eval(n))
```

Comment: n is like this : 2 * x ^ 2 - 2 * x + 2
Can I enter it like this !

Comment: It should  be fine the use eval even if you have spaces, if you want to remove all the spaces you could run: `n=''.join(n.split())`

Answer (score 1):

Actually for what i understand, you don't need to input n.

```
x = int(input('Enter x value: '))
def f(x):
    return 2*x**2 - 2*x+2

n = f(x)
```

Edit, after rereading others answer yes it probably wanted eval()
Just You can't write "2 * x ^ 2 - 2 * x + 2", the correct way is x**2 instead of x^2

Answer (score 0):

You mean (?):

```
def f(x, n):
    return n*x**2 - 2*x + 2
```

Or do you mean actually changing the operators?

The question as currently posed is mathematically impossible. You define x & n and are returning a function that you may or may not want to equate to n but its all defined entries.

Still guessing a little at the actual question, but if

```
y = input("Enter equation to evaluate")
```

and you expect y to be a quadratic, i.e.:

```
y = "a*x**b - c*x + d"
```

then you can get all them from:

```
import re
y1 = re.split('[* ]',y)

a = y1[0]
b = y1[3]  #as there is a null ent between the ** we skip y1[2] and y[1] is 'x'
c = y1[5]
d = y1[8]
```

If you wanted the operators, then it gets a little harder to follow. So we'll cross that bridge if you do need them.

Or, as the others suggest, just use eval()!!

Comment: how input this in n = input('enter method')
 n*x**2 - 2*x + 2

Comment: So the user would enter a string such that you'd have in your variable space;  n = "n*x**2 -2*x + 2"  ?

If the two 'n' entries are independent, might I suggest changing one of them to reduce confusion? i.e. y = "n *x **2 -2*x + 2"

Comment: The user is required to enter an equation by writing it like this one
n*x**2 - 2*x + 2
He writes it completely in the input function and the program analyzes it and distinguishes the operations of multiplication, division and subtraction through symbols